# Axios can't send credentials

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to include credentials to my requests

I'm using axios but axios don't send credentials with request. 
This is how i do it with axios.

```
const axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
};

axios
  .get("someurl" + data, axiosConfig)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But when i try it with fetch everything work.

```
fetch("someurl" + data, {
  credentials: "include"
})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

how make it work with axios too?

Answer (score 1):

You should see the `auth` parameter inside the axios config object

```
auth: {
   username: 'janedoe',
   password: 's00pers3cret'
}
```

see https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: İ didnt understand

Comment: What do you mean by credentials? try to put an exemple with dummy text credentials, so I can explain better

Comment: İ mean cookies So at axios Docs written that it’s possible with withcredentials:true

Comment: Have you tried to pass it as the bearer of your Authorization parameter inside header ?     `headers: {Authorization: \`Bearer ${cookie_value}\`}`